# Two way binding is not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a form to submit data to a database, first time when page is loaded, it is working fine but after first submit ,When we click submit for second value then console shows bad request, this is because of all the values are null in $scope.

When I debuging js step by step then again its working.

How to fix this issue.

$scope.Save = function () {

```
    var MainMenuRecord =
        {
            MainMenuId: $scope.Form.MainMenuId,
            MainMenu: $scope.Form.MainMenu,
            PageTitle: $scope.Form.PageTitle,
            PageUrl: $scope.Form.PageUrl,
            MainMenuOrder: $scope.Form.MainMenuOrder,
            UpperText: $scope.Form.UpperText,
            LowerText: $scope.Form.LowerText,
            UpperStatus: $scope.Form.UpperStatus,
            LowerStatus: $scope.Form.LowerStatus,
            HomePanelStatus: $scope.Form.HomePanelStatus,
            PageId: $scope.Form.PageId
        };
    var promisePost = MainMenuService.post(MainMenuRecord);
    promisePost.then(function (pl) {
        alert('Mainmenu ' + pl.statusText + ' Successfully.');
        Clear();
        $scope.Form.pageNumber = 1;
        LoadRecord();
        console.log(pl.data);

    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Err" + err.Message);
    });

}
```

and service is

```
app.service('MainMenuService', function ($http) {

    //create new record
    this.post = function (tblmainmenu) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/api/MainMenuAPI",
            data: tblmainmenu
        });
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're being way too vague.

Comment: Two way binding IS working, but you need to give us more details.

Comment: Show the code. How do you send the values?

Comment: Send data using $http ,you may be loosing scope while sending request

Comment: its done actually problem in clear() mathod

Answer (score 0):

> this is because all the value are null in $scope.

Answered your own question. Whatever is populating your scope is working. Check your controller or service or factory or whatever it is that's populating the scope, and determine why it's not working on the second request.